# How can I integrate this html within this php loop?

Tags: php

I have this PHP code I am trying to integrate with the html layout below it however I can not figure it out, the php
code gets all status post and displays them in order but it then displays all comments that are associated with the status post so a status post could have
0 comments or it could have multiple comments.

If you read the notes I left in the PHP code and the notes I left in the html you will see the problem I am facing
I need to put the comments inside the table cell of the status post somehow

In the image below there is 1 status post and 3 comments for that post, what I am trying to do is get the comments to show up in there own table that will be nested in the right side right under the status post.  So on the status post @ the top you see a table border at the bottom of that post, that border should be below the last comment for that post, hope that makes a little more sense now

[image]

```
<?PHP
$last_id = 0;
echo '<table width="400">';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    //start output of new status post and comments
    if ($row['0'] != $last_id) {
        echo 'status post stuff'
    }
    //start output of new status post and comments

    //output comment here
    $last_id = $row['0'];
    if($row['commentid'] != ''){
        echo 'status COMMENT for above status post'
    }
    //END output comment here
}
echo '</table>';
?>

<table width="400">

    <!-- begin status post -->
    <tr> 
        <td width="99" valign="top" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); margin: 0px; padding-top: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 10px;"> <div class="imageSub" style="width: 90px;"> <img class="female" src="http://cache2.mycrib.net/images/image_group66/0/43/t_6871399b0962b5fb4e29ce477541e165950078.jpg" alt="Something" width="90"/> </div></td>
        <td width="489" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); margin: 0px; padding-top: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 10px;">so and so said blah blah blah @ wee hours of the moring! <BR>

            <!-- begin comment -->
            <table width="90%" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); margin: 0px; padding-top: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 10px;">
                <tr>
                    <td width="14%" rowspan="2" valign="top"><img class="male" src="http://cache2.mycrib.net/images/image_group34/0/39/T_653807517aff2b1f5662d865b40d87d527c8eb.jpg" alt="Something" width="45"/></td>
                    <td width="86%">Date Posted</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Comment text</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- end comment -->

        </td>
    </tr>
  <!-- end status post -->

</table>
```

Comment: I'll be honest with you, I don't understand what the problem is that you're facing. Care to elaborate? :)

Comment: I added a picture and a little more description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can close your php tag to drop into html again then reopen it inside your loop.

e.g.:

```
<table width="400">

<?PHP
$last_id = 0;
echo '<table width="400">';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    //start output of new status post and comments

    if ($row['0'] != $last_id) {
        //echo 'status post stuff'
     ?>
<tr> 
            <td width="99" valign="top" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); margin: 0px; padding-top: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 10px;"> <div class="imageSub" style="width: 90px;"> <img class="female" src="http://cache2.mycrib.net/images/image_group66/0/43/t_6871399b0962b5fb4e29ce477541e165950078.jpg" alt="Something" width="90"/> </div></td>
            <td width="489" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); margin: 0px; padding-top: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 10px;">so and so said blah blah blah @ wee hours of the moring! <BR>
     <?php
    }
    //start output of new status post and comments

    //output comment here
    $last_id = $row['0'];
    if($row['commentid'] != ''){
        echo 'status COMMENT for above status post'
    }
     //END output comment here
     ?>

                <!-- begin comment -->
            <table width="90%" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); margin: 0px; padding-top: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 10px;">
                <tr>
                    <td width="14%" rowspan="2" valign="top"><img class="male" src="http://cache2.mycrib.net/images/image_group34/0/39/T_653807517aff2b1f5662d865b40d87d527c8eb.jpg" alt="Something" width="45"/></td>
                    <td width="86%">Date Posted</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Comment text</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- end comment -->

      <?php
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: Ok wow I am very suprised but that actually worked, thank you

Answer (score 4):

I would try something like this, it allows you to separate the design from the logic which is fetching stuff from the database.

1.Build an array from your database which is something like below - this should be straightforward:

```
<?php
$posts = array(
    array( 
        'title' => 'Hello',
        'post' => 'This is the post',
        'comments' => array( 
            array(
                'date_posted' => '28/07/2009',
                 'text' => 'this is the first comment'
            ),
            array(
                'date_posted' => '28/07/2009',
                'text' => 'this is the second comment'
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Another post',
        'post' => 'Hello',
        'comments' => array()
    )
);
?>
```

2.Loop through array and output html (I have simplified but you should be able to adapt).

```
<?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
    <!-- begin status post -->
    <h1><?php echo $post['title']; ?></h1>
    <p><?php echo $post['post']; ?></p>
    <?php if ($post['comments']): ?>
        <h2>Comments:</h2>
        <ul>
        <?php foreach ($post['comments'] as $comment): ?>
            <!-- begin comment -->
            <li>
                <?php echo $comment['text']; ?>
                etc.
            </li>
         <!-- end comment -->
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
<!-- end status post -->
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I like this I am just now learning array so I always wanted to do something like this so thanks for the example hopefully I can get something like this working eventually

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you start learning a templating system such as [SMARTY](http://www.smarty.net/) which will make a lot of your problems a lot easier to solve and your code a lot easier to read and understand.

Comment: smarty complicates things, php itself is a templating system if used properly

Comment: I actually used smarty before, i'm not a fan of templets IMO it's just more code to parse